# Yii routing issue when use module

Tags: php, yii, routes, yii-url-manager, yii-routing

I want to use my url manager something link that.For my blog details

**http://example.com/yii-fremwork-install** => it gose to blog controller details method

where "yii-fremwork-install" is slug of come from database.

and also wont a module for that i write my url manager something like that

```
'rules' => array(
                '<slug:.+>' => 'users/details',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            ),
```

But when i rty to use my admin module

**http://example.com/admin**
 it go to user/details controller hoe to use this

Can some one give some idea  to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `<slug:.+>` is used for every route.

You have to manually define all you controller in the rules array and define them first

Like this :

```
'rules' => array(
            '<controller:admin|default|item>' => '<controller>',
            '<controller:admin|default|item>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:admin|default|item>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:admin|default|item>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<slug:.+>' => 'users/details',
        ),
```

Where your 3 other controllers are (as an example) `AdminController`, `DefaultController` and `ItemController`

Comment: And if you add a first line with just `<controller>` ? Like I did in editing my answer

Comment: I have solved this issue using '<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>/?' => 'users/ServiceProfile',